# assign in NON-ARC and retain cycle

Tags: ios, weak-references, assign, retain-cycle, weak

How retain cycle was tackled in NON-ARC !

I know assign is an alternative to weak.

weak will have its value set to nil If object allocated is deallocated whereas assign is not

so how it was done earlier can anybody help me understand

Comment: Without ARC you were responsible for performing `retain` and `release` operations. You could keep a reference without `retain` but this isn't the same as `weak` because if the object is released you are left with an invalid pointer. This is why non-ARC was a pain and is best forgotten

Comment: so back then also what kind of property declaration was used (assign) or something else ?

Comment: You could use `assign`, `copy` or `retain`. The default was `assign` while with ARC the default is `strong` (`retain`)

Comment: @Paulw11 - so in week we'd check if its nil before performing the operation ...so how to check invalid pointer in NON-ARC ?

Comment: Access it and see if your program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Zeroing weak references (what ARC calls `weak`) only exist under ARC.

Non-zeroing weak references (what ARC calls `unsafe_unretained`) can be used in MRC or ARC, and is the only kind of "weak reference" that is used in MRC.

You are asking how to avoid dangling references with non-zeroing weak references. You just have to design the logic of the program so that it doesn't happen. It's not that hard.

Usually, a "parent" object will have strong references to "child" objects, and then a back-reference from the "child" object to the "parent" will be a weak reference (in this case a non-zeroing weak reference). All you have to do is, when the "parent" object is deallocated, in its deinitializer, `nil` out the back-references that the "child" objects have to it -- it can access these "child" objects since it has a reference to them.

Comment: so in the dealloc method of parent we've to mark self=nil.. can you please explain me with a small code example ? I don't really understand the deinitializer part.

Comment: so in week we'd check if its nil before performing the operation ...so how to check invalid pointer in NON-ARC ?

Comment: @vinoth.kumar: In the `dealloc` method of the parent object, it would do something like `childObject.delegate = nil;`, where here the child object holds a weak reference called `delegate` to the parent.

Comment: @vinoth.kumar: It's impossible to "check" an invalid pointer -- it is undefined behavior in C to use an invalid pointer at all.